# Query slows down in Conditional IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I noticed that the following took 32 seconds to run in SQL Server (2008 R2)

```
IF  ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view1) != 0)
    OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view2) != 0)
    OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view3) != 0)
    OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view4) != 0)
    OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view5) != 0)
    OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view6) != 0)
        PRINT 'HI'
```

Yet, the following only took 4 seconds

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view1)
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view2)
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view3)
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view4)
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view5)
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viwe6)
```

I have managed to optimize the conditional by doing SELECT COUNT(1)... + SELECT... != 0 such that it takes 4 seconds but looking at the execution plans haven't yielded anything particularly notable. Haven't had much chance with googling the word OR either.

Could someone please share what SQL Server optimizer is potentially doing behind the back?

EDIT: IF EXISTS attempt took 38seconds.

```
IF EXISTS ((SELECT 1 FROM view1)
    UNION (SELECT 1 FROM view2)
    UNION (SELECT 1 FROM view3)
    UNION (SELECT 1 FROM view4)
    UNION (SELECT 1 FROM view5)
    UNION (SELECT 1 FROM view6))
        PRINT 'HI'
```

EDIT2: The current 5 second method.

```
IF  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM view1)
  + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM view2)
  + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM view3)
  + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM view4)
  + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM view5)
  + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM viwe6) != 0
        PRINT 'HI'
```

EDIT3: After comparing the 20page sized query plans - it appears the speedup is mostly due to underlying views are doing a partial aggregate before their joins as opposed to doing joins then aggregates.

Comment: You get much better performance by doing EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM view1 ), as this will stop looking after it finds one row, rather than counting all of the rows.

Comment: I did try EXISTS. But it also took about 38 seconds. I'll put what I tried in the edit.

Comment: A quick thought put count result into variable  then use IF condition

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma I do have a working solution which is fast (see EDIT2) - just seeking as to why it performs so slowly.

Comment: I seriously doubt the SQL Server optimizer is doing something not shared the the query plan.  Post the query plans.

Comment: Nested views can cause the query optimizer to have issues especially when they get deep.  Rule of thumb is to follow the percentages and attack the large percentages individually.

Answer (score 1):

How long does the code below take for you to run? If you convert your query to `EXISTS`, you will want to avoid the UNION since in your example you're forcing SQL to `UNION` every row from each of your views and then seeing if an element exists. The answer below will be opportunistic to stop as soon as possible.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM view1)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM view2)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM view3)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM view4)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM view5)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM view6)
    PRINT 'HI'
```

Here's an alternate approach with TOP with a single exists - perhaps based on the provided explanations on why the multiple EXISTS were performing so slowly for you should be much better.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM view1
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM view2
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM view3
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM view4
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM view5
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM view6
    )
    PRINT 'Hi'
```

As for your question on under the hood, the url below has a good writeup:
http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/comparing-exists-vs-left-join-where-not-null

Basically, it describes that a work table is not created when using `EXISTS`, so with single statements with multiple `EXISTS`, the performance can get slow as in your case.

Comment: Not much luck, this took 29 seconds.
I speculate that the problem is not 'exiting' ASAP - but rather the underlying SQL optimization engine doing a poor execution plan due to the if statement. I'm still questioning why and what it may be doing under the hoods.

Comment: Can you run the alternate query? I added some information and a link to a blog post on why multiple EXISTS like this can be slower for some scenarios.

Comment: What is interesting is the execution plan is identical for both of the above queries, but supposedly the single EXISTS should be more optimized

Comment: The alternate query is 28 seconds - so it single exists is indeed more optimized

Answer (score 1):

use TOP 1 statement :

for example:

```
DECLARE @CONTROL INT;
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM view1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM view2
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM view3
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM view4
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM view5
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM view6)

SELECT @CONTROL = COUNT(col) FROM CTE

IF @CONTROL != 0
PRINT 'HI'
```